# What is the equivalent of `\space` command in em value in TeX?

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

Currently I'm learning how to create a macro to design my own document format, and the `\space` command is often used. I want to know its exact value in `em` value or `pt` value. If anyone can shine some light on this that will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

`\space` is defined by

```
\def\space{ }
```

so it adds a space token not glue.

When typesetting horizontal space as determined by fontdimens and `\spacefactor` and `\xpacefactor` will be added just as for a literal space.

One of the most common uses in macro writing is in messages.

```
\typeout{\string\LaTeX\space zzz}
```

produces a message `\LaTeX zzz` where clearly `\space` is just a character and not any length in `em` units.

Comment: @DCarlisle You mean `\space` is actually a font dependent value like em, and can't be measured in `pt` or `in`, right?

Comment: @Jiapan No I mean it is defined exactly by the line that I showed. It is not a tex primitive it is just a trivial macro with that definition. It expands to a space token it is not font dependent at all. Any apparent dependence on the font is due to the behaviour of a literal space character. In the `\typeout` there is no current font at all.

Comment: @DCarlisle So is there any way to measure `\space` in `pt` value?

Comment: note `@Dcarlisle` does not ping me, I see ones under my answer anyway, or it as to match my user name (`@D` and then chose from the options.)  `\space` is just ` ` so it really doesn't have a lot of meaning to ask its length. if you are in horizontal mode and if you are not under the influence of `\ignorespaces` then it will make a space of natural width fontdimen 2 with stretch fontdimen3 and shrink fontdim4, as modified by the current spacefactor, unless `\spacefactor` or `\xspacefactor` have been set in which case they are used instead of the font dimens.

Comment: But none of the above is anything to do with `\space` just as if you go `\newcommand\foo{x}` there is nothing special about `\foo` it just expands to `x` and then does whatever `x` does,

Comment: @jia i sense you want something different. Do you want a defined space by having multiple \spaces?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, I think I knew what you mean, thank you very much!

Comment: @Johannes_B No, I just want to replace those spaces in pt or in units

Comment: @Jiapan consider a use like `\count0=5\space`   here `\space` does not correspond to a width at all it is simply terminating the number, the same as `\count0=5 `

Answer (score 2):

`\space` like spaces that you insert with your keyboard can stretch and shrink. You can get the length of an "unstretched" space by measuring a box or by requiring \fontdimen2 of the current font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
a\space b

a\space b \linebreak c %stretched \space

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{\mbox{ }}
\the\mylength = 
\the\fontdimen2\font

\bfseries 
\settowidth\mylength{\mbox{ }}
\the\mylength =
\the\fontdimen2\font

\end{document}
```

[image]